# Difficulty making a Morse to English translator via Python 3

Tags: python, morse-code

So Here is what I have for my English-morse translator (which works fine):

```
english = {'.-': 'a',     '-...': 'b',   '-.-.': 'c', 
    '-..': 'd',    '.': 'e',      '..-.': 'f',
    '--.': 'g',    '....': 'h',   '..': 'i',
    '.---': 'j',   '-.-': 'k',    '.-..': 'l',
    '--': 'm',     '-.': 'n',     '---': 'o',
    '.--.': 'p',   '--.-': 'q',   '.-.': 'r',
    '...': 's',    '-': 't',      '..-': 'u',
    '...-': 'v',   '.--': 'w',    '-..-': 'x',
    '-.--': 'y',   '--..': 'z',

    '-----': '0',  '.----': '1',  '..---': '2',
    '...--': '3',  '....-': '4',  '.....': '5',
    '-....': '6',  '--...': '7',  '---..': '8',
    '----.': '9', ' ': '          '}

    print ("""


================================================================================
                      English to Morse Code Translator
================================================================================""")
time.sleep(2)
while True:  
    msg = input('''What would you like translated? please use lower-case letters.\n   :''')
    print ("")
    for i in msg:
        print(morse[i])
    userstatus = input('Would you like to go again?(y or n): ').lower().strip(' ')
    if userstatus not in('y', 'yes'):
        print ("Have a nice day!")
        break
```

Now this works fine, what I am having problems with is the Morse-English translator:

```
morse = {'a': '.-',     'b': '-...',   'c': '-.-.', 
    'd': '-..',    'e': '.',      'f': '..-.',
    'g': '--.',    'h': '....',   'i': '..',
    'j': '.---',   'k': '-.-',    'l': '.-..',
    'm': '--',     'n': '-.',     'o': '---',
    'p': '.--.',   'q': '--.-',   'r': '.-.',
    's': '...',    't': '-',      'u': '..-',
    'v': '...-',   'w': '.--',    'x': '-..-',
    'y': '-.--',   'z': '--..',

    '0': '-----',  '1': '.----',  '2': '..---',
    '3': '...--',  '4': '....-',  '5': '.....',
    '6': '-....',  '7': '--...',  '8': '---..',
    '9': '----.', ' ': '          '}


    print ("""
================================================================================
                      Morse to English Code Translator
================================================================================""")
time.sleep(2)
while True:  



    msg = input('''What would you like translated?
:''')
    print ("")
    for i in msg:
        print(english[i])
    userstatus = input('Would you like to go again?(y or n): ').lower().strip(' ')
    if userstatus not in('y', 'ye', 'yes'):
        print ("Have a nice day!")
        break
```

ans = input('''press 1 for English to Morse\npress 2 for Moris to English
    :''')

The problem I am having with this is that once I enter a line of Morse code, such as "-- --- .-. ... .", it prints it out like this:

```
    What would you like translated?
    :-- --- .-. ... .

t
t

t
t
t

e
t
e

e
e
e

e
Would you like to go again?(y or n):
```

Does anyone know I way I can fix this so it will print out the word, in this case morse, instead of only t or e?

Comment: try `for i in msg.split(" "):` rather than `for i in msg:`

Comment: Morse is a 4-letter alphabet. There are dots and dashes; there are also long and short pauses.

Answer (score 2):

Split the input message on spaces, then iterate over the whole Morse patterns.  Iterating one character at a time only reads a single dot or single dash.

This should fix it:

```
for i in msg.split():
    print(english[i])
```

Comment: This would fix the dictionary look up, but it's still only going to print one character per line

Comment: @aruisdante Of course, just like OP's "works fine" English to Morse code prints one morse letter per line. That didn't seem to be the goal at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here. The first problem is that in English, your letters are one character wide, so your naive `for letter in message` approach works.

In Morse, however, your 'letters' are an arbitrary number of characters wide. Therefore, you need to [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) your input message around the delimiter that represents the end of a Morse character-point. In this case, that appears to be the `' '` character. Fortunately, Python has a method for that, `str.split(delimiter)`. And the default delimiter happens to be `' '`. So, you'd do:

```
tokens = msg.split()
letters = [english[token] if token else '' for token in tokens]
```

But you have another problem; you have to re-join the characters together into words after you've translated them. Fortunately, Python has the inverse of `split`, which is `str.join`. In this case, you'd do:

```
translated = ' '.join(letters)
print(translated)
```

If you want to get really fancy, you can actually combine the two steps into one, like so:

```
translated = ' '.join(english[token] if token else '' for token in msg.split())
```